# Is there a contradiction between 1 Timothy 5:20 & Galatians 2:2

Tags: contradiction, galatians, 1-timothy

Timothy 5:20 (NKJV)

20  Those who are sinning rebuke in the presence of all, that  the rest also may fear.

Galatians 2:2 (NKJV)

2 And I went  up by revelation, and communicated to them that gospel  which I preach among the Gentiles, but privately to those  who were of reputation, lest by any means I might run, or  had run, in vain.

In Galatians Paul knew that there was bound to be a confrontation with the Jews in Jerusalem,it seems he did his best he could not to publicly rebuke those of the reputation who most likely were wrong but rather chose to speak to them privately which was a direct contrast to his teaching in 1 Timothy. Was Paul compromising in this situation or he feared that confronting the leaders of the church in Jerusalem might damage his reputation

Comment: Not my DV, but it would help in understanding your interpretation of this question, and therefore understanding more precisely in understanding what you are looking for, if you explain why you believe "In Galatians Paul knew that there was bound to be a confrontation with the Jews ... rebuke those of the reputation who most likely were wrong ".  I think the consensus is that Gal 2:2 does not lead to the conclusion that he would rebuke them.

Comment: The "communication" of Gal 2:2 is **not** a rebuke for sin: it is a testing of Paul's message. Read a little further to see how [Gal 2:11-14](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Galatians+2%3A11-14&version=NIV) fits in wholly with the counsel of 1 Tim 5:20. Meanwhile, the question as posed is a non-question.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying principle in both passages is how disputes within the Church should be handled. Jesus gave instruction on this:

> *15 “If your brother sins against you, go and tell him his fault, between you and him alone. If he listens to you, you have gained your brother. 16 But if he does not listen, take one or two others along with you, that every charge may be established by the evidence of two or three witnesses. 17 If he refuses to listen to them, tell it to the church… (Matthew 18:15-17 ESV)*

There is a 3 step process:

1. Private: Handle it between the parties.
2. Semi-private: Involve a few others.
3. Semi-Public: Bring it before the church (semi-public as there is no instruction to make the issue to to those outside the Church.)

Paul's description of his action in Galatians indicate he is using the process Jesus taught. He is presenting his teaching privately before a small group; this is the semi-private step. In other words, Paul did not go only to one person (eg Peter), he went to a small group of reputable people.

1 Timothy 5:20 is giving instruction on how Timothy should handled "those" who persist in sinning, after he has heard, and decided the matter described:

> *Do not admit a charge against an elder except on the evidence of two or three witnesses. (1 Timothy 5:19 ESV)*

5:19 describes the semi-private meeting and 5:20 describes what to do if that does not resolve the matter and the problem persists (despite Timothy's decision).

There is no conflict between the two passages. Paul's semi-private meeting in Jerusalem resolved the question. There was no need for him to go before all the church; he continued to preach the message to the Gentiles.